# etale neighbourhood of a product

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am interested in the analog between etale and usual topology. The following question is one example. Any reference would be appreciate.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $X_1$ and $X_2$ be $k$-varieties. My question is as follows: For a given etale neighbourhoods $U,u\to X_1\times_k X_2,(a_1,a_2)$, are there etale neighbourhood $U_1,u_1\to X_1,a_1$ and $U_2,u_2\to X_2,a_2$ such that the induced etale morphism $U_1\times_k U_2, (u_1,u_2) \to X_1\times_k X_2$ can be factored through $U,u$?

Comment: Define $U_1$ to be the fibre product of $U$ with $X_1\times\{a_2\}$ over $X_1\times X_2$. The induced morphism $U_1\to X_1\times \{a_2\}$ is etale. Define $U_2$ similarly.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: I don't think that works. In general $U_1 \times U_2$ is not contained in $U$ (even if you work with Zariski opens). Concrete example: let $X_1 = X_2 = \mathbb A^1$, with $a_1 = a_2 = 0$, and let $U$ be the complement of the hyperbola $V(xy - 1)$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Hoi Remy, you're right. I just constructed etale maps $U_i\to X_i$, but they don't verify the property that $U_1\times U_2 \to U$ is etale necessarily. Thanks!

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, Ariyan Javanpeykar: many thanks for your answer, and sorry for my bad formulating of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the example I gave in the comments shows that such $U_i$ do not exist in general:

**Example.** Let $X_1 = X_2 = \mathbb A^1$, with base points $a_1 = a_2 = 0$. Let $U = D(xy-1)$ be the complement of the hyperbola $xy = 1$.

Suppose there exist étale neighbourhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ of $0$ such that $U_1 \times U_2 \to \mathbb A^2$ factors through $U$. Since étale maps are open, the (set-theoretic) images of $U_1$ and $U_2$ in $\mathbb A^1$ are opens $W_1, W_2 \subseteq \mathbb A^1$ containing $0$. Then the image of $U_1 \times U_2 \to \mathbb A^2$ is $W_1 \times W_2$.

But no such set can miss $V(xy-1)$: there are only finitely many $x$ not in $W_1$, and only finitely many $y$ not in $W_2$. Thus, for almost all $x \neq 0$, we have $x \in W_1$ and $\tfrac{1}{x} \in W_2$, providing a point
$$\left(x,\tfrac{1}{x}\right) \in V(xy-1) \cap W_1 \times W_2.$$
We conclude that such $U_i$ cannot exist. $\square$

**Remark.** Basically, the Zariski topology (!) has too few opens.